# Determine $\mathbb{E}[X]$ with known pdf $f(x)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expectation

Say we have probability density function $$f(x) = \frac{a}{(x+a)^2}.$$ Here $a>0$ and $x\geq 0$. I've already checked that $\int_0^\infty f(x) = 1$. However I've trouble determining the expected value. I know that: $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^\infty x\ f(x)\ \text{d}x,$$ however Wolfram says that this intergral does not converge. Is there something wrong with the pdf? Or is there another way to get the expectation? Is it possible that a well define pdf has no expectation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomax_distribution  You are dealing with the Pareto / Lomax distribution with $\alpha = 1, \lambda = a$. When $\alpha = 1$, the expectation does not exist as what you found. It is possible for a distribution to have no first moment. Another heavy-tailed distribution, frequently quoted as the counter example, is the Cauchy distribution.

Comment: But what is the interpretation of having no mean? It sounds strange right?

Comment: Some may argue its amazing that an infinite integral converges at all :)

Comment: $E(X)$ exists iff $E(|X|)<\infty$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom - but here $X \ge 0$ so that do not help very much

Comment: Your distribution has a heavy right tail, so heavy that the mean is infinite, i.e. does not converge